# Is $(a,f(a))$ a point of inflection if $f'(a)=0$ and $f''(a)=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For a polynomial $f$, if we know that $f'(a)=0$, and that $f''(a)=0$, would the point $(a, f(a))$ be considered a point of inflection?  I do not think it would, but I am having trouble visualizing it.

Edit:  What I am really asking is, given $f'(a)=0$, if we know that $f''(a)>0$ implies a minimum, and that $f''(a)<0$ implies a maximum, does $f''(a)=0$ directly imply anything? Is there any particular significance to that point of the graph like there is to minimums, maximums, points of inflection. etc?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^4$ and the point $(0,0).$

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. A point of inflection is where $f''(a)$ **changes** sign.

Simply knowing that $f''(a)=0$ does not imply a point of inflection, but it is **necessary** to have a point of inflection.

As @mfl commented, $\displaystyle \frac{d^2}{dx^2}x^4=0$, but $f(x)=x^4$ doesn't have a point of inflection at $x=0$.

Whereas, $\displaystyle \frac{d^2}{dx^2}x^5=0$ and it does have a point of inflection at $x=0$.

Comment: This isonly for continuous functions right?